# How can i return to matrix my printed matrix calculations in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm super new on R programming. I did just basic calculation, I use print to check my results but I can't return to a matrix on environment section my results. Plus I have 3/11 matrix but I got results for 11/3.

```
Ut<-rbind(T2,T3,T4)    
Uort<-rbind(MT2,MT3,MT4)    
for (i in 1:11) { 
    print(Ut[ ,i]-Uort[ ,1])}
```

Here is my code ,T2,T3,T4 and MT2,MT3,MT4 they are vectors and I used rbind to be occurred to a matrix. I think it may be so simple for others but for me not. Hope there are someone who can help me to solve this.

Comment: May be you need `Ut[,i, drop = FALSE] - Uort[, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

If we are extracting a single column/row, the `?Extract` will use `drop= TRUE` by default,

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

thus coercing the `matrix` or `data.frame` to a vector by removing the `dim` attributes.  An option is to specify `drop = FALSE` in one of the dataset

```
for(i in 1:11) {
  print(Ut[,i, drop = FALSE] - Uort[, 1])
 }
```

NOTE: `print` only prints the output to the console.  If we need to store the output, create an object for storing

```
out <- matrix(NA, nrow(Ut), ncol(Ut))
for(i in 1:11) {
    out[, i] <- Ut[, i] - Uort[, 1]
  }
```

---

In `R`, these operations can be done without a `for` loop

```
Ut - Uort[,1]
```

Comment: I did without using for loop after your comment and it worked.Thank you so much .It helped me.          
  Uf<-Ut - Uort[,1]      Uft<-t(Uf) .now im trying to find another matrix called A means sum(Uf*Uft) ,then i think i need for loop for this but can i do it without for loop too?